# Make SVG children focusable in FF, IE

Tags: javascript, svg

[image: HTML FOR THE SVG]I am trying to create a hotSpotMatching page where the user has to select a shape rendered via SVG.

To make this accessible I am trying to use the tab key to get focus on my svg children. I am using ReactJS to generate my JS code.

This is my render method:

```
renderShape(shape) {
        let className = (shape.selected ? 'shape-selected' : 'shape-unselected');
        let svgWidth = this.state.width;
        let svgHeight = this.state.height;
        let shapeKeyDownCallback = this.toggleShapeSelection(shape);
        if (shape.hotSpotShapeType === 'CIRCLE') {
            /* CIRCLE */
            let cX = Math.round(shape.point.x * svgWidth);
            let cY = Math.round(shape.point.y * svgHeight);
            let cRadius = Math.round(shape.radius * svgWidth);

            return (
                <circle cx={cX} cy={cY} r={cRadius} className={className} aria-selected={shape.selected} tabIndex="0" onClick={this.toggleShapeSelection(shape)} onKeyDown={this.handleShapeKeyDown(shapeKeyDownCallback)} />
            )

        } else if (shape.hotSpotShapeType === 'RECTANGLE') {
            /* RECTANGLE */
            let rectX = Math.round(shape.upperLeft.x * svgWidth);
            let rectY = Math.round(shape.upperLeft.y * svgHeight);
            let rectWidth = Math.round(shape.lowerRight.x * svgWidth) - Math.round(shape.upperLeft.x * svgWidth);
            let rectHeight = Math.round(shape.lowerRight.y * svgHeight) - Math.round(shape.upperLeft.y * svgHeight);

            return (
                <rect x={rectX} y={rectY} width={rectWidth} height={rectHeight} className={className} aria-selected={shape.selected} tabIndex="0" onClick={this.toggleShapeSelection(shape)} onKeyDown={this.handleShapeKeyDown(shapeKeyDownCallback)} />
            )

        } else if (shape.hotSpotShapeType === 'POLYGON') {
            /* POLYGON */
            let polygonPoints = shape.points.map((point) =>
                Math.round(point.x * svgWidth) + ',' + Math.round(point.y * svgHeight)
            ).join(' ');

            return (
                <polygon points={polygonPoints} className={className} aria-selected={shape.selected} tabIndex="0" onClick={this.toggleShapeSelection(shape)} onKeyDown={this.handleShapeKeyDown(shapeKeyDownCallback)} />
            )
        }
    }
```

The issue that I am facing is the tabindex=0 works well in Chrome but IE, FF ignore this property.

I read that if I surround my children tags with anchor tags it will work but that fails too.

e.g I tried to return

```
<a href="www.example.com" className="svg-link">
  <circle> .... </circle>
</a>
```

but this does not make my circle component focusable in FF. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a couple days I could not figure it out.

I created this hack fix

I created buttons and moved them offscreen and when I got focus on them I would call my renderShape method but with a className of 'shape-highlighted'. This will just draw an outline over the svg shape.

This is not the perfect fix so if someone has a better way please tell me.